# The application DGAgent quit unexpectedly -- repeatedly pops up every time i "ignore", "report" or "relaunch"

Tags: macos, software, imac

Before this problem occurred I have been trying to defrag my disk using Drive Genius 3 and repair using disk utiltity.  Than I decided to delete it.  Not sure if that was the reason or not but after that I had this message pops up all the time "The application DGAgent quit unexpectedly".  I have no idea what it is.  This happens every I start up my iMac.  The message pops up every time I click "ignore" "report" and "relaunch" buttons.  Can you tell me what it is and how to fix it?  Also this causes some of my applications such as Skype "cannot be opened because it is not supported on this architecture".

Answer (score 1):

The error you're getting from Skype is because you're not using an Intel-based Mac.  Skype only runs now on Intel-based Macs so I assume you're running a PowerPC iMac G5 or something are you?  You also need to be running Leopard/Snow Leopard.  Here's a screenshot of the System Requirements on the [Skype Download page](http://www.skype.com/intl/en/get-skype/on-your-computer/macosx/):

[image: Skype System Requirements]

So, the Skype issue is not related to the DGAgent message.

---

As regards the startup of DGAgent on login, you can try the following:

1. Open System Preferences
2. Click Accounts
3. Select your account
4. Click Login Items
5. Highlight Drive Genius if it's listed and click the '-' button on the lower left to remove it.

This will prevent OS X from attempting to start it on login.  See screenshot below.
[image]

Comment: Griffo,  thank you for taking the time to answer my questions.  I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Jon No problem, did you try that?  Did it work?

Comment: As for the login items, Drive Genius is not listed.  I only have ItunesHelper and dropbox in the list.  I removed both of them as well but it didn't work.  The pop up still appears on screen.

Comment: is this going to take a long time and what will happen at the end?  It's been running for about 2 minutes already

Comment: Sorry yeah it will take a long time that's why I deleted it to see if I could figure out a quicker way.  Press control+c to cancel it.  I'll come back to you in a few minutes

Comment: what do i do there?

Comment: OK, try this command in Terminal, it will take time but it should find where on the system DGAgent is located, then you may be able to remove it.  `sudo find / -type f -name DGAgent* -print`

Comment: Macintosh:~jon$ find / -type f -name DGAgent* -print
find: /.Spotlight-V100: Permission denied
find: /.Trashes: Permission denied

Comment: don't know why but i have admin rights

Comment: Sorry I made an edit, you have to put `sudo` in front.  This means 'Super User Do'

Comment: Macintosh:~ jon$ sudo find / -type f -name DGAgent* -print
find: /dev/fd/3: Not a directory
find: /dev/fd/4: Not a directory

Comment: that's what i got

Comment: Yeah those are normal messages, has it finished running?

Comment: find: /dev/fd/3: Not a directory
find: /dev/fd/4: Not a directory
/Library/Application Support/DriveGenius/DGAgent.app/Contents/MacOS/DGAgent
/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/DGAgent_2011-01-27-215817_Macintosh.crash
find: /net/localhost: Operation timed out
find: /net/broadcasthost: Operation timed out

Comment: should I reinstall Drive Genius?

Comment: OK the two timed out messages are expected.  You could try deleting `/Library/Application Support/DriveGenius` and everything in that directory.  That might solve your issue because that appears to be where the app is located

Comment: I deleted that folder but still didn't work :(

Comment: Did you empty the trash?  It's not deleted until trash is emptied.  Also, make sure you reboot

Comment: yep it is emptied

Comment: So you still get the error complaining that DGAgent quit unexpectedly?

Comment: yes the error pops up over and over again when i click ignore button and relaunch buttons

Comment: Were there any other files found containing `DGAgent` from that command I gave you earlier?  Anything after `/net/broadcasthost: Operation timed out`?  Did you see my updated answer above in relation to the Skype errors?

Comment: those are the errors and nothing after when it timed out.  I also still get the same error on skype as well.

Comment: What type of Mac are you using?  Does it have an Intel processor?

Comment: thanks i wiped out everyhing and installed new osx and it's gone.  thanks for all your help